# How to format this kind of date?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

How can I format dates in this style: `Sun Aug 11 00:54:13 BRT 2019`?

I have a table that has dates using this format in a `varchar` column and I would like to insert as `datetime` in another table.

I tried:

```
select date_format('Sun Aug 11 00:54:13 BRT 2019', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

For testing, but it returns `NULL`.

Also, does this kind of style has a name?

Comment: `I would like to insert as datetime in another table` ...in that case it makes no sense to try and format the date, because datetime fields don't have a format. Just convert it to a date object directly (as per the answer below). Formatting is the process of converting a date to a string, whereas you are trying to convert a string to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you neeed to convert a string to a date. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for that purpose.

Consider:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
    'Sun Aug 11 00:54:13 BRT 2019',
     '%a %b %e %H:%i:%S BRT %Y'
);
```

Yields:

```
2019-08-11 00:54:13
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Qofq24S9ASRqmQRkDxHR2/0)**

NB:

- from your sample data it is not possible to tell if the day of the month is stored as `0..31` (specifier `%e`) or as `00..31` (specifier `%d`)
- I left the timezone apart